# Date class setMonth sets weird values

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, datetime, actionscript

I have the following test code:

```
    var d1 : Date = new Date("2016/02/20 15:00:00 UTC-0000");
    trace(d1.toUTCString());
    d1.monthUTC++;
    trace(d1.toUTCString());

    var d2 : Date = new Date("2016/03/31 15:00:00 UTC-0000");
    trace(d2.toUTCString());
    d2.monthUTC++;
    trace(d2.toUTCString());
```

This traces

```
[trace] Sat Feb 20 15:00:00 2016 UTC
[trace] Sun Mar 20 15:00:00 2016 UTC
[trace] Thu Mar 31 15:00:00 2016 UTC
[trace] Sun May 1 15:00:00 2016 UTC
```

Why does date in the second example jump 1 month and 1 day instead of just one month? (from Mar. 31th to May 1st)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution lies in how internally the Date class works:

When I have a date that is set to the 31th of the month, for example:
    `"2016/03/31 15:00:00 UTC-0000"`
and I increase the month by one, internally it becomes:
    `"2016/04/31 15:00:00 UTC-0000"`
Then this is resolved internally again. But since April has only 30 days the date overflows to May:
    `"2016/05/01 15:00:00 UTC-0000"`

Same thing would happen if I try to set the `date` field to the 31th of April.

Also this means that the official ActionScript documentation is wrong:

> `setUTCMonth()`
>   Sets the month, and optionally the day, in universal time(UTC) and returns the new time in milliseconds. Calling this method does not modify the other fields, but the Date.getUTCDay() and Date.getDay() methods might report a new value if the day of the week changes as a result of calling this method.

They did not think of this edge case, when setting the month alters the date too.

The same thing happens in JavaScript too.